# Flutter/Dart TimeOfDay object returns TimeOfDay(15:00) instead of only the time

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, timeofday

i want to print the Time that i initialized manually but if i print it then i only get this here.

```
I/flutter (14375): TimeOfDay(15:00)
```

Here is my Code

```
Future<void> ausgabe(BuildContext context) async {
Map<String, TimeOfDay> zeiten = {"Montag": TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0)};
print(zeiten["Montag"]);

}
```

How can i only print 15:00 instead of TimeOfDay(15:00)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use:

```
TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0);
print(time.format(context));
```

Or you can do that with `DateFormat` from the [intl flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

```
print(DateFormat("HH:mm").format(new DateTime(
    2000,
    1,
    1,
    time.hour,
    time.minute)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `format()` method

```
Map<String, TimeOfDay> zeiten = {"Montag": TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0)};
TimeOfDay time = zeiten["Montag"];
print('${time.hour}:${time.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}');
```

Comment: I/flutter (14375): 3:00 PM
I wanted in 24H format